# Install latest Rsymphony Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, r

One could install [`Rsymphony`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsymphony/index.html) by doing:

```
apt-get install r-cran-rsymphony
```

But that is an old version. When trying to install the latest (from within `R`), one get:

```
* installing *source* package ‘Rsymphony’ ...
** package ‘Rsymphony’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Cannot find SYMPHONY libraries and headers.
See <https://projects.coin-or.org/SYMPHONY>.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘Rsymphony’
```

How to install the latest Rsymphony package?

Comment: The documentation says it needs *"SYMPHONY libraries and headers"* - these appear to be provided by the [coinor-libsymphony-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coinor-libsymphony-dev) package - did you install it?

Comment: Indeed, `sudo apt-get install coinor-libsymphony-dev` fixed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Rsymphony documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsymphony/index.html) indicates that it needs SYMPHONY libraries and headers:

> ```
> NeedsCompilation:     yes 
> SystemRequirements:   SYMPHONY libraries and headers
> ```

In Ubuntu, these appear to be provided by the [coinor-libsymphony-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/coinor-libsymphony-dev) package. Installing that, either using your favorite GUI package manager or from the command line using

```
sudo apt install coinor-libsymphony-dev
```

should solve the issue.